# Present a view controller from top to bottom direction

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, ios9

How can I present a view controller from top to down direction in Swift?

I have a view controller with a notification(bell) icon at the top. When I click this icon, I want to show a view controller that originates from top.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default transition style that will give you this effect. But you can use custom animations applied on view controller to acheive this effect. These are some links you can follow.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/113845/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions

[How do you present a UIViewController from the top of the screen instead of the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264678/how-do-you-present-a-uiviewcontroller-from-the-top-of-the-screen-instead-of-the)

Answer (score 1):

There is an control available to presenting a `uiviewcontroller` as a popup with different type of animations.

[MJPopupViewController](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController) try it may be it help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Making a custom transition as suggested above
2. Add view controller as child view controller and animate it from top.